# Write a sql query to add column to dataframe with substring from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse

I have written a sql query which brings datafarame which looks like this:

```
ID        event                    date                               message
1     connection                 2020-11-19            connection was garbage collected 
2     connection                 2020-11-19            In addition: Warnings 
3     myid                       2020-11-19            Value passed to replic (MYID= 806320110310:00, OLDID= 4289)
4     myid                       2020-11-19            Value passed to replic (MYID= 349812948:00, OLDID= 1969)
5     warning                    2020-11-19            Warning message
```

Here is a sql query to get this:

```
WITH
   value LIKE '%connection was garbage%' AS connection,
   value LIKE '%Value passed to replic (MYID%' AS myid,
   value LIKE '%Warning message%' AS warning
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID,  
  multiIf(
     connection as 'connection',
     myid as 'myid',
     warning as 'warning',
     NULL) as event,
  date,
  value as message
FROM my.data.frame
WHERE 
  connection
  OR myid
  OR warning
```

Now, I want to add another column "MYID", which is equal to value from message of event myid. Desired result is:

```
ID        event                    date                               message                                                         myid
1     connection                 2020-11-19            connection was garbage collected                                                NA         
2     connection                 2020-11-19            In addition: Warnings                                                           NA
3     myid                       2020-11-19            Value passed to replic (MYID= 806320110310:00, OLDID= 4289)               06320110310:00
4     myid                       2020-11-19            Value passed to replic (MYID= 349812948:00, OLDID= 1969)                  349812948:00
5     warning                    2020-11-19            Warning message                                                                 NA
```

How could I do that in my sql query? How could I extract that number value and out it in new column?

Comment: just remark: string processing on each select is pretty bad practice; consider either insert not raw data but already parsed one (where defined event type, ids, etc.) or use [Materialized View](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view/#materialized) to do it on ClickHouse side.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    'Value passed to replic (MYID= 806320110310:00, OLDID= 4289)' AS s,
    extract(s, '.*MYID= (.*),.*') AS myid

┌─s───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─myid────────────┐
│ Value passed to replic (MYID= 806320110310:00, OLDID= 4289) │ 806320110310:00 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```